# How to transform table values to column headings

Tags: r

Im trying to manipulate my data such that the values in each column become column headings, and the values for each of these columns are their previous column name.

My table can be produced with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble("#" = c(1,2,3),
             "1" = c("a","a","b"), 
             "2" = c("b","b","c"), 
             "3" = c("c","c","a"))
```

My current table looks like this:

```
# 1 2 3
1 a b c
2 a b c
3 b c a
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
# a b c
1 1 2 3
2 1 2 3
3 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `order` applied to each row of the `tibble`:

```r
## new column names
names(df) <- c("#", sort(unlist(df[1, -1], use.names = FALSE)))

## apply order to each row of df
df[, -1] <- t(apply(df[, -1], 1, order))

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>     `#`     a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     2     3
#> 2     2     1     2     3
#> 3     3     3     1     2
```

**Disclaimer**: this assumes that each row contains a *permutation* of all available variables. If this is not the case, (e.g. twice the letter `a` in a single row), there would be an issue assigning individual values to each column.